# Set values to comboBox using iText

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I have already created **PDF** and i want to assign values to **comboBox** in it using **iText**. But i haven't found any solution. I tried passing `string array` to `setValue()`. but `setValue()` method accepts only `string` not `string array` so getting error.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader, new PdfWriter(dest));
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
Map<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.getFormFields();
fields.get("Name").setValue(emp.getEmployeeName()).setBackgroundColor(Color.ORANGE);
fields.get("Combobox").setValue([]string{"en", "hi"});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String dest = "D:/filename.pdf";
         // get original pdf template
         PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
         PdfStamper filledOutForm = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
         AcroFields fields = filledOutForm.getAcroFields();
 // available options in dropdown can be specified by using following line
 fields.setListOption("Country Combo Box",new String[]{"India", "USA", "Pakistan", "Bangladesh"}, new String[]{"India", "USA", "Pakistan", "Bangladesh"});
       // selected option out of available
      fields.setListSelection("Country Combo Box", new String[]{"India"});
```