# Set Combobox value is adding weird characters... (C#)

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I am using iText7 for a project. We need to export data to a PDF programmatically.

It is working fine for simple textfields, textareas and for checkboxes. But is it doing weird stuff when we are trying to set values onto dropdownlist (combobox).

Foreach of the above combobox, the options are :
`Critique; Important; Modéré; Faible;`

Here is the code inside a self alone program.cs file :

```cs
using iText.Forms;
using iText.Forms.Fields;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;

public class Program
{
    public static readonly string CHECKED_STATE_VALUE = "Yes";
    public static readonly string UNCHECKED_STATE_VALUE = "Off";

    private static void ConsoleOutFieldData(PdfFormField field)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(field.GetFieldName() + ": " + field.GetValue());
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"C:\code-test\CERTAQ-FORM-17-001-Declaration_d_incident.pdf");
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(@"C:\code-test\test1.pdf");

        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
        PdfAcroForm? form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
        var fields = form.GetFormFields();

        Console.WriteLine("Before :");
        ConsoleOutFieldData(form.GetField("cbImpactA"));
        ConsoleOutFieldData(form.GetField("cbImpactB"));
        ConsoleOutFieldData(form.GetField("cbImpactC"));
        ConsoleOutFieldData(form.GetField("cbImpactD"));

        // Combobox
        form.GetField("cbImpactA").SetValue("Critique");
        form.GetField("cbImpactB").SetValue("Modéré");
        form.GetField("cbImpactC").SetValue("Important");
        form.GetField("cbImpactD").SetValue("Faible");

        Console.WriteLine("After :");
        ConsoleOutFieldData(form.GetField("cbImpactA"));
        ConsoleOutFieldData(form.GetField("cbImpactB"));
        ConsoleOutFieldData(form.GetField("cbImpactC"));
        ConsoleOutFieldData(form.GetField("cbImpactD"));

        // Rendre les champs non modifiables.
        form.FlattenFields();
        pdfDoc.Close();
    }
}
```

Here is the result into the console and on the PDF output :

```
Before :
cbImpactA: Modéré
cbImpactB: Critique
cbImpactC: Faible
cbImpactD: Important
After :
cbImpactA: þÿCritique
cbImpactB: þÿModéré
cbImpactC: þÿImportant
cbImpactD: þÿFaible
```

On the PDF Output you can see that the values seem to contain new line character.
[image: PDF Screenshot]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I tried to do this solution in C# : [Set values to comboBox using iText (JAVA)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50210297/20325571) without any success. The function doesn't seem to exist in C#.

Comment: I didn't set the value to þÿCritique. It did it automatically as I set it to Critique. Why will it be þÿ C r i t i q u e with space between each letter ? What should I see on the PDF analyser that tell me what is wrong? @KJ

Comment: The first injection is set with an PDF viewer like chrome. I set the default values from chrome. Then, with iText7, I set the value to another one. Maybe there is a setting to modify inside iText class instances ?

Comment: Here is the PDF file : https://filebin.ca/7LPQNgUKls0h/CERTAQ-FORM-17-001-Declaration_d_incident.pdf

Comment: It is still not working. I don't know what is happening with iText7. Could be an issue in the library...

Comment: Do you think we should try to delete and recreate the field with a PDF editor ?

Comment: @Maxime Which iText 7 version exactly are you using? The have been some recent overhauls in the iText 7 form APIs...

Comment: It is the version 7.2.5 @mkl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@K J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10802527/k-j) helping me to find the problem.

Here is what I did to fix my problem :
I removed the 4 dropdown fields from the form then I recreated them. I used [DocFly](https://www.docfly.com/) to edit my PDF for FREE.

Look at the results now :)

[image]

[image]